# Using python twitter library how can i extract the list of users follow a particular #hashtags anonymously?

Tags: python, twitter

So, I have a problem statement in which I want to extract the list of users who are following a particular `#hashtag` like `#obama`, `#corona` etc.

The challenge here is I want to extract this data anonymously i.e without providing any account keys.

I tried a library named `twint` that is capable of doing this but it's very slow. can anyone recommend a better alternative for my use case..?

Comment: Um, is there even a Twitter feature of following a certain hashtag? I'm a Twitter user and I can't find any feature like this.

Comment: This is not possible - there's no way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no such library available that satisfy your use case. yes there's this twint library but as you mentioned it's slow for your use case. so try with some other language libraries see if something is available over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make a scripts in python using selenium, and I think that you could get that names of users very fast.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sho_Lee but I am looking for a opensource python library with the help of which I can directly communicate with the twitter library and the response needs to be really fast I am not looking crawler for now. I meantioned my use case in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This Github repo which I found might be useful. It does not require authentication to get the twitter data. Have a look at it -https://github.com/bisguzar/twitter-scraper

Answer (score 1):

I tried this approach last year, but found out that my date range fell well outside of the available info provided by Twitter, and had to use the Premium API. If this is not a constraint for you, and since you do not want to code your own scraper, take a look at this option:

[TweetScraper](https://github.com/jonbakerfish/TweetScraper): Updated in September last year, also provides MongoDB integration. I haven't tried it, but seems to work OK. Don't know about the time performance.